# Generally speaking, is there an "order" to the basics in an External CSS file

Tags: css, external

I am just learning External CSS, with help from a couple people.  I am trying to compare and combine two sheets into one but because 2 people wrote them, I need to sort out the names they gave for IDs and classes.  One sheet became very extensive, but the other sheet has some updated info I want to keep.

I generally understand inheritance, but I don't think my questions below relate to inheritance.  I just want to know if there's a standard order to use in a CSS file?

So, first question:
On a triple border (3 table) layout, why do both authors have a table ID for body followed by visited link info, THEN they go to Table ID for middle border, then Table ID for innermost (content) border?  Can't the 3 border IDs be listed one after the other, and then go on to the link section?  Or does the link section need to be in the body section?

Is there any specific order I must use for the sections, like page fonts, H1-H6 sizes,  celled-table (vs borer tables) styles, etc. ?

Lastly, is there an EASY way to compare the 2 files so I can move needed items into 1 CSS file?

Comment: You should post your code in your question, then read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS is learning barrier is extremely low, and as you mentioned, elements of inheritance when combining multiple css classes can become chaotic. Especially if you have the same element listed twice. The untangling can be maddening.

A best practice design pattern (when you have the luxury), is to use a css standard and stick with it:

@mdo offers up a [fantastic style guide](http://codeguide.co/) which if followed, can eliminate the issues of merging external css style sheets. mdo talks specifically about attribute order [here](http://codeguide.co/#html-attribute-order).

In addition, read Krasimir's post about [CSSSteel](http://krasimirtsonev.com/blog/article/csssteal-chrome-extension-that-extracts-css). It is a fantastic look at how to deal with adding css in site with complex css elements.

Other than manually, here are some automated tools that might assist:

- ## try: [Gtmetrix](https://varvy.com/pagespeed/combine-external-css.html)

  A online css analyzer, gtmetrix is a css tool that automates the analysis of a sites css. I can't image it is perfect and the level of success is
  proportional to the css sheet complexity.
- ## try: [CSSLint](http://csslint.net/)

  This might be overkill, CSSLint is another online css analyzer. But of the many [lint rules](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/should-you-start-using-csslint--net-20895) it processes is (illustrating duplicate properties) The CSSLint motto is "Linting works best when we see the big picture, so give us everything you've got." and "Will hurt your feelings"
- ## try: [Stylebot](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylebot/oiaejidbmkiecgbjeifoejpgmdaleoha?hl=en)

  A chrome addon, Stylebot allows you to pick an element and choose any changes you want to make from the editor. You can change the font, color, margins, visibility and a lot more. You can also write CSS manually. This might assist in determining duplicate problems with your merged stylesheet.
- ## try: [SnappySnip](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/snappysnippet/blfngdefapoapkcdibbdkigpeaffgcil?hl=en)

  Whats great about this chrome addon, is that it allows you to easily extract CSS and HTML from selected element. Then send it to CodePen, jsFiddle or JSBin with one click.

Comment: I'm unsure whether it was Sevle or Fergus who gave the list of CSS tools.  Thank you.  I tried CSS Lint on both css files and both have zero errors.  Now I just need to find a novice fool-proof method to combine the two sheets.  Thank you again.